# 403 forbidden in admin console: fix seems to be temporary and then error is back

Tags: errors

I've already cleared my browser cache, checked the server's file permissions, deactivated all plugins and none of those options fix the 403 code error. Only deleting the htaccess file works. However, the next day the problem is back and I have to regenerate the htaccess file again.

This is something I can do manually, but this website is supposed to be operated by people with little technical knowledge, so I can't ask them to deal with htaccess.

The frontend works fine and the main page of the admin console works as well. It's any other page in the admin console that throws this error.

I checked the old htaccess and these are its contents:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-theme.php|wp-scripts.php|wp-editor.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

After regenerating it, the contents are these:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I find out what's triggering the changes on this file and prevent it? Or would it be safe to just remove write permissions so the file is not changed at all?

Comment: these look like security additions either by a host or a security plugin, you should inquire with them, otherwise I'm not sure how this can be answered here